# ofstream not outputting when I don't have a endl c++

Tags: c++, sockets, client, server

I have a client/server socket program that writes packets of file data in a char[2048], I've made 100% sure to null terminate all of the arrays before sending over the socket.

However on the server side I can't get the ofstream to output to the file if I do not have an endl, however this endl inserts itself at the end of the packets and makes the file have newlines in them where I don't want them to.

Here is what should be the relevant code

client

```
void Copy(char *filename1,string filename2,int Sockfd) {

    const int BUFSIZE=2048;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    ifstream fin;


    long filelen, bytesRemaining, bytes;

    // Open the file to be transferred, check it exists.
    fin.open( filename1);
    if (!fin.good()) {
        cerr << "Problems opening \"" << filename1 << "\" (" << errno << "): " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // Determine the file's length.
    fin.seekg(0,ios::end);
    if(fin.fail()) cerr<<"seekg() fail!\n";
    filelen = fin.tellg();
    if(fin.fail()) cerr<<"tellg() fail!\n";
    fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    if(fin.fail()) cerr<<"seekg() fail!\n";


    // Copy the file data.
    bytesRemaining = filelen;
    while (bytesRemaining > 0)
    {
        bytes = bytesRemaining > BUFSIZE ? BUFSIZE : bytesRemaining;

        buffer[bytes] = '\0';




        fin.read(buffer,bytes);
        if(fin.fail())
        {
            cerr<<"read() errror\n";
            exit(1);
        }


        send(Sockfd,buffer,sizeof buffer,0);


        recv(Sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);

        bytesRemaining -= bytes;
    }
    fin.close();

}
```

And Server

```
    int retval;
    char EchoBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE];        // Buffer for echo string
    int RecvMsgSize;                    // Size of received message





    std::ofstream fout;

    fout.open("test.txt",std::ios::ate);




    // Send received string and receive again until end of transmission
    while(RecvMsgSize > 0)
    { // zero indicates end of transmission

        // Echo message back to client
        if(send(ClntSocket, EchoBuffer, RecvMsgSize, 0) != RecvMsgSize){
            perror("send() failed"); exit(1);
        }
        // See if there is more data to receive



        if((RecvMsgSize = recv(ClntSocket, EchoBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE-1, 0)) < 0){
            perror("recv() failed"); exit(1);
        }


        EchoBuffer[RecvMsgSize] = '\0';
        fout << EchoBuffer << endl; //If I don't have this endl, it won't work at all




    }

    fout.close();
    close(ClntSocket);    // Close client socket
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Have you tried `fout.flush()` after  `fout << EchoBuffer;`?

Comment: I just tried, it was the problem indeed, earlier when I googled it mentioned that endl flushed, but didn't think much of it, huge thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write `fout.flush();` after `fout << EchoBuffer;`.